# Spring boot rest response gives 1 result on OneToMany when there are multiple objects in database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

For a school project, we have to make a spring boot rest server that communicates to our MySQL database. Here is a screenshot of the database:

[image]

For my user model I have the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@Setter
public class User extends ResourceSupport implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_user", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonSerialize
    private Long id;
    @Getter
    private String firstName;
    @Getter
    private String lastName;
    @Getter
    private String email;
    @Getter
    private String password;
    @Getter
    private Double hourlyWage;
    @Getter
    private String adress;
    @Getter
    private String city;
    @Getter
    private Boolean isManager;
    @Getter
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_to_project", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"))
    private List<Project> projects;
```

Then for my project class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
@Setter
public class Project extends ResourceSupport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_project")
    @JsonSerialize
    private Long id;
    @Getter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company owner;
    @Getter
    private String description;
    @Getter
    private String name;
    @Getter
    private double payout;
    @Getter
    private boolean internal;
    @Getter
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_to_project", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> users;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because this is the result I am getting:

[image]

while I have this in my link table:

[image]

I Hope someone has an answer to my question because I'm getting sick of spring boot and this school project.

Comment: Your Project and User relation isn't OneToMany, it is ManyToMany. Correct your entities.

Comment: @BorLaze thanks for the quick response! but sadly that still doenst fix the problem... You are correct though, so thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know will it help you or not, but below is my code:

```
// Role
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("roles")
@OrderBy("id")
private List<User> users;

// User
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("users")
@OrderBy("id")
private List<Role> roles;
```

Also, take attention - instead of SQL where m2m tables are equals, in JPA one table is "master" (User in my example) and other one "slave". "Slave" should have modifier `mappedBy` in @ManyToMany annotation.

Table DDLs (postgres):

```
create table roles
(
  id               serial                not null
    constraint roles_pkey
    primary key,
  version          bigint default 0
);

create table users
(
  id               serial                not null
    constraint users_pkey
    primary key,
  version          bigint  default 0
);

create table users_roles
(
  user_id integer not null
    constraint fk_users
    references users,
  role_id integer not null
    constraint fk_roles
    references roles,
  constraint users_roles_pkey
  primary key (user_id, role_id)
);
```

I hope it will be helpful. Good luck.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help but sadly the code you supplied still didnt help. Would you by any chance be able to post a screenshot of your tables? that way i know i have my JoinColumn names set right

Comment: @Joris van Roy, I added DDLs to my post - check it.

Comment: thank you for helping so much! i finally got it, after i set hibernate to print sql lines i figured out that i did put in the wrong joincolumn names... Thank you so much again, this was a big headache for me hahah